# How to use Lambda in LINQ select statement

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, lambda

I am trying to select stores using a lambda function and converting the result to a SelectListItem so I can render it.  However it is throwing a "**Type of Expression in Select Clause is Incorrect**" error:

```
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> stores =
    from store in database.Stores
    where store.CompanyID == curCompany.ID
    select (s => new SelectListItem { Value = s.ID, Text = s.Name} );
ViewBag.storeSelector = stores;
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

Also, how do I convert Int to String in this situation?  The following does not work:

```
select (s => new SelectListItem { Value = s.ID.ToString(), Text = s.Name} );
select (s => new SelectListItem { Value = s.ID + "", Text = s.Name} );
```

EDIT 2:

Figure out the Int to String conversion.  It is so typical of Microsoft to forget to include an int2string conversion function.  Here is the actual workaround everyone is using, with fully working syntax:

```
select new SelectListItem { Value = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)store.ID), Text = store.Name };
```

To call this situation absurd is an understatement.

Answer (score 134, accepted):

using LINQ query expression

```
 IEnumerable<SelectListItem> stores =
        from store in database.Stores
        where store.CompanyID == curCompany.ID
        select new SelectListItem { Value = store.Name, Text = store.ID };

 ViewBag.storeSelector = stores;
```

or using LINQ extension methods with lambda expressions

```
 IEnumerable<SelectListItem> stores = database.Stores
        .Where(store => store.CompanyID == curCompany.ID)
        .Select(store => new SelectListItem { Value = store.Name, Text = store.ID });

 ViewBag.storeSelector = stores;
```

Comment: Can you please help me convert int to string?  There seem to be no way for LINQ to Entity to convert int to string.

Comment: @YongkeBillYu You mean like for example `5.ToString()`?

Comment: Can you create another question and show the code for what you are doing?

Comment: @RussCam, if I am not wrong . `Where(store => store.CompanyID == curCompany.ID)` is of type Func<> lamda expression???

Comment: @Kgn-web yes, a `Func<T, bool>` is passed to `.Where()`, where `T` is the type in `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: @RussCam. Thanks for your inputs. Irrespective of this question, can you please give me scenario where we use Action<> or Predicate<> lamda expression in LINQ. (You may use https://codepaste.net/ for sharing the snippet).

Comment: @Kgn-web use `Action<T>` when you want to pass a delegate that doesn't return a value and `Predicate<T>` delegate where you need to return a boolean value; `Predicate<T>` was introduced in .NET 2.0, and generally `Func<T, bool>` is more often used, which was introduced in .NET 3.5 IIRC.

Comment: @RussCam.Thanks mate :)

Answer (score 20):

Why not just use all Lambda syntax?

```
database.Stores.Where(s => s.CompanyID == curCompany.ID)
               .Select(s => new SelectListItem
                   {
                       Value = s.Name,
                       Text = s.ID
                   });
```

Answer (score 17):

You appear to be trying to mix query expression syntax and "normal" lambda expression syntax. You can either use:

```
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> stores =
        from store in database.Stores
        where store.CompanyID == curCompany.ID
        select new SelectListItem { Value = store.Name, Text = store.ID};
ViewBag.storeSelector = stores;
```

Or:

```
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> stores = database.Stores
        .Where(store => store.CompanyID == curCompany.ID)
        .Select(s => new SelectListItem { Value = s.Name, Text = s.ID});
ViewBag.storeSelector = stores;
```

You can't mix the two like you're trying to.

Answer (score 5):

Lambda Expression result

```
var storesList = context.Stores.Select(x => new { Value= x.name,Text= x.ID }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Lambda expressions:

1. If we don't have a specific class to bind the result:

   ```
    var stores = context.Stores.Select(x => new { x.id, x.name, x.city }).ToList();
   ```
2. If we have a specific class then we need to bind the result with it:

   ```
   List<SelectListItem> stores = context.Stores.Select(x => new SelectListItem { Id = x.id, Name = x.name, City = x.city }).ToList();
   ```

Using simple LINQ expressions:

1. If we don't have a specific class to bind the result:

   ```
   var stores = (from a in context.Stores select new { x.id, x.name, x.city }).ToList();
   ```
2. If we have a specific class then we need to bind the result with it:

   ```
   List<SelectListItem> stores = (from a in context.Stores select new SelectListItem{ Id = x.id, Name = x.name, City = x.city }).ToList();
   ```