# Lambda function in LINQ select clause

Tags: c#, linq, syntax, lambda

Imagine a code like this:

```
return from pair in pairs.AsParallel()
       let var1 = ... // var1 is typeof(int)
       let var2 = ...
       let var3 = ...
       let var4 = ...
       let var5 = ...
       let var6 = ... // var6 is typeof(IEnumerable<int[]>)
       from v in var6
       select { v[0] = var1; return v; };
```

The LINQ select clause does not allow this construction, but I can do that with normal lambda select statement like:

```
foo.Select(v => { v[0] = var1; return v; });
```

Because of the amount of "let" clauses I need, I would prefer to use the first syntax rather than second. How can I do that? I just need to assign a value (based on complex calculations in the query) to the first item of the `v` array and then return the whole array.

There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15577890/how-to-use-lambda-in-linq-select-statement) which does not offer any solutions unfortunately. I was under the impression that both types of writing the query are completely equivalent, so how can I do this?

Comment: IMHO, mutating input values in linq expressions goes against the functional programming aspect of linq and isn't necessarily the best idea.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: You are absolutely right, unless u have millions of records and tight performance requirements ... I could do the same thing with a bunch of .Concat(...).ToArray(), but that is just orders of magnitude slower.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you can do this only in the query. The description [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384087.aspx) says that it lists all the possible forms a `select` can have. As well, I know that you can't use a `let` with a lambda expression.

There is a workaround to let you  get a similar result. You could create a separate function and call that in your select:

```
int[] MyFunc(int[] a, int var1)
{
    a[0] = var1;
    return a;
}

//In the query:
from v in var6
select MyFunc(v);
```

If you don't want to make a new function everytime you call this, you can also define a delegate outside of the query, make an instance of it with a lambda function, and call the lambda function in the query in the same way.

```
delegate int[] MyDelegate(int[] x, int y);
MyDelegate del = (v, var1) => { v[0] = var1; return v; }; //<--lambda goes here

//Start query
return from pair in pairs.AsParralel()
    ...
    from v in var6
    select del(v, var1);
```

It doesn't look great, but it works.

Comment: Ah well it's funny, what I can also do is this: "let a = b.Select(x => { x[0] = var1; return x })" and "select a" :-D what a silly syntax

Comment: @Paya Yah, that would work too. I think its gonna look ugly no matter what you do :P