# WCF throwing type mismatch error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf, utf-8

I have the following wcf function using EF6:

```
public Order GetNextOrderNotDownloaded()
{
    return _context.Orders
                .Include(o => o.OrderLines)
                .Where(o => !o.IsDownloaded)
                .OrderBy(o => o.DateCreated)
                .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

But when I try to invoke this in the test client I get an exception thrown saying the connection is being terminated.  Through following other posts I added diagnostics to the web.config and found the exception was

> *Content Type application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 was sent to a service expecting text/xml; charset=utf-8.  The client and service
>   bindings may be mismatched.*

I've tried various things like changing the binding in the web.config and removing the `textEncoding="utf-8"` and then other posts suggested it may be a serialisation problem so I tried adding the `[Serializable]` attribute to the `Order` and `OrderLines` classes but that didn't work either.

If I remove the `.Include(o => o.OrderLines)` it will return me the `Order` object but I need those orderliness too.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

**Web.config binding:**

```
<basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="basicHttpBinding_Service" 
                closeTimeout="00:11:00" openTimeout="00:11:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:11:00" 
                allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" 
                maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" 
                messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
        <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
        </security>
    </binding>
</basicHttpBinding>
```

Further to this, if I recreate the `Order` and `Orderline` classes without links to EF (that is without data annotations and virtual properties) and populate them with the values got from the entities, the WCF will start working so why would the "clone" classes work but the EF classes don't

Answer (score 0):

Create a OrderDTO object with contains Oder property and IEnumerable of Orderline

```
Public class OrderDTO 
{
    Int ID;
    //......
    IEnumerable<Orderline> Orders;
}
```

Change the return type to OrderDTO

```
public OrderDTO GetNextOrderNotDownloaded()
```

And in the LINQ query create lambda expression for Select query see it @ [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15577890/how-to-use-lambda-in-linq-select-statement)
Your final code will look like this.

```
public OrderDTO GetNextOrderNotDownloaded()
{
    return _context.Orders
                .Include(o => o.OrderLines)
                .Where(o => !o.IsDownloaded)
                .OrderBy(o => o.DateCreated)
                .Select(o => new OrderDTO { Id = o.Id, Orders = o.OrderLines})
                .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: How's that going to help? The OP has a problem with calling the service, not executing the query.

Comment: OP mentioned in his last point says "Further to this, if I recreate the Order and Orderline classes without links to EF (that is without data annotations and virtual properties) and populate them with the values got from the entities, the WCF will start working."

Comment: I tried an OrderDTO but as soon as I added the order lines to it, it failed again

Comment: What do you mean by adding order lines, Where did you add it? Did you update the reference at client side? To update the client proxy.

Comment: At the end of my question the order and orderline clones are dtos.  I tried mapping the original orderlines to the order dto as you have said and it failed

Comment: I would like to recommend you following things: 1) Give us exactly the exception you are getting now. 2) Check if you have updated the client web reference. 3) Debug and check if you are able to call the web method on Service side and it returns correct OrderDTO

Answer (score 0):

`text/xml` is used by SOAP 1.1 while `soap+xml` by SOAP 1.2. In .NET, SOAP 1.1 is used by BasicHttpBinding while SOAP 1.2 by WSHttpBinding. Does your test client use WsHttpBinding?

Your service can provide endpoints that support both protocols but your clients should connect to the endpoint that supports the protocol version they want to use.

Comment: I have added https binding but am currently unable to test it as my self signed certificate isn't working locally