# List <string> smart way to remove characters from items

Tags: c#

I have a string List ; the goal is to remove the "RGBI1" characters from the items.
What could be the best approach to achieve this. Trying to learn other ways to handle this situation. P.S loop inside loop not my cup of tea. Thank you for your time.

E.G

```
List<string> stringlist = new List<string> 
    {  
        "RGBI1red", 
        "green", 
        "RGBI1pink", 
        "purple"
    };
```

Comment: You might want to check out `string.Replace`.  Note that strings are immutable so you will have to assign the result back to the list.

Comment: `stringlist.select(x=>x.replace('RGBI1', '')).ToList();` You could use Linq. Note, this does not modify the original string.

Comment: I think you haven't searched for this on internet yet....

Comment: Do you want to remove the characters in the string "RGBI1" from the list, or  only occurrences of the entire substring? In the latter case, do you want to remove all occurrences, or only those where the give strings starts with the substring as per your example?

Comment: Thank you all for the prompt reply. I will give LINQ stuff a quick try. @Daniel Shillcock and Ricardo Serra for good pointers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My suggestion would be to use LINQ. See an example below:

```
List<string> stringlist = new List<string> { "RGBI1red", "green", "RGBI1pink", "purple" };
stringlist = stringlist.Select(s => s.Replace("RGBI1", string.Empty)).ToList();
```

Using the list that you've made, this select query will replace all `RGBI1` with nothing. This then is converted into a list by the use of `.ToList()`.
Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15577890/how-to-use-lambda-in-linq-select-statement) for more information.

Comment: You don't need to specify generic parameter for `ToList()` method - it will be inferred from source type

Answer (score 0):

An answer using LINQ would be:

```
        var stringlist = new List<string> { "RGBI1red", "green", "RGBI1pink", "purple" };
        stringlist = stringlist.Select(x => x.Replace("RGBI1", "")).ToList();

        stringlist.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x));

-->
   red
   green
   pink
   purple
```

Answer (score -1):

Why would you need two loops, surely just one? Loop through the strings and do a replace. Any other solution will do this under the covers anyway..... But here it is in LINQ: 
.   stringlist.Select(s => s.Replace("RGBI", "");

Comment: No point in adding the same answer as given by others. Also please consider adding some code to show the process to loop and replace.